# Changing the id from an element and do some action with the new id

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the id from an element and use the new id for example i have a button with `id="show-categories"` and then if i click the button the id change to `id="hide-categories"`.

This one works good

```
       $("#show-categories").on('click', function(event){
            $("#inactive-categories").show();
            $(this).attr('id', "remove-categories");
            $(this).html("Close");
        });
```

but this one is not working

```
        $("#hide-categories").on('click',function(){
            alert('hi')
        });
```

It's necessary to destroy the first and create a new one?? or i can work this way

Thanks

Edit:

Well if i can use ID's i was trying to do something different

```
      $("#show-categories").on('click', function(event){

        if($(this).hasClass("remove")){
            $("#inactive-categories").fadeOut();
            $(this).removeClass("remove");
        }
        else{
            $("#inactive-categories").show();
            $(this).unbind('click');
            $(this).addClass("remove");
            $(this).html("Cerrar");
        }


    });
```

Comment: HTML and CSS post it in a [mcve], thank you.

Comment: The ID's don't match and even if they did the new ID doesn't exist at the time the code runs. This really sounds like an XY problem. Explain what problem you are trying to solve by even considering switching the ID

Comment: Note a really important point here. The event listeners are assigned to an element , regardless of that element ID changing later on. The original event listener will still exist

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $(document).on('click','#hide-categories',function(){

        alert('hi')
    });
```

Comment: Sure this will make a new listener available after the ID changes but won't help OP due to the original even listener will still exist. This solves part of the problem but leaves some ugly issues lingering

Answer (score 0):

try binding the 'hide-category' click right after your change the id:

```
$("#show-categories").on('click', function(event){
        $("#inactive-categories").show();
        $(this).attr('id', "remove-categories");
        $(this).html("Close");
        $(this).unblind('click');
        $(this).click(hideCategories);
    });

function hideCategories() {
  alert('hi') 
}
```

Comment: why change the ID at all?

Comment: I wouldn't change the id either but that was the question.

Comment: No that was an XY problem solution probably guided by a misconceived concept of how event listeners work and a beginner always wanting to use ID selectors

Comment: well charlie im a beginner if you can give a solution i will listen it